# Playstore reported crashes that are not linking to app codebase (ssize_t BitTube::recvObjects)

Tags: android, android-gui

I am getting this error on playstore but not on Appcenter crashes. I am unable to find the root cause of this issue. Please provide any leads on this.It looks like a crash in Bittube cpp file in android framework code.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/libs/gui/BitTube.cpp

and it seems to be related to gui https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/native/libs/gui/DisplayEventReceiver.cpp

File.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I need a microscope to read your images.  Please post as text, not as images.

Comment: haha @PaulMcKenzie, but I hope you can click the image and see the full resolution image